# Systemd unit auto restart when network changes

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I am using a Python script to make some connection to a remote server. This is my unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python...
WorkingDirectory=/home/matej/...
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, this works fine, but when my network changes (i. e. changing WiFi, turning WiFi off and back on, putting laptop in sleep mode and bringing it back,...), this script needs to be restarted in order to reestablish my connection.

Currently I need to do it by hand every time network changes (`sudo systemctl restart myconnection.service`).

But I guess, there is an option that this is handled automatically? Any help on this?

Comment: Do you have `NetworkManager.service`  in your systemd services? Try running `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` if you get an error then maybe the system are using another service but If you get an output about the status of that service please let me know.

Comment: And how do you want your `myconnection.service` behaves? If you turn off your wifi the `myconnection.service` should be stopped and if you turn on the wifi the `myconnection.service` should be started? Or do you want to **restart** the service either wifi is on/off?

Comment: ```sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
```

Comment: I would like that when WiFi is turned on (or Ethernet or any other connection is on), immediately after that my service is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you do have `NetworkManager.service` then you also should have the `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service` and therefore the path `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.
What you can do to be able to detect when a connection is **up** or **down** is enabling and starting `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service` systemd service:

```bash
# --enable now: will enable and start the service at once
sudo systemctl enable --now NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

Before creating the script which will check the status of the network interface you will have to get the network interfaces available in your system. You can use `ip a` or `ifconfig` to get that:

```
$> ip a
#Output:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:93:4a:8f:03:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp1s0
    inet 192.168.1.71/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 85690sec preferred_lft 85690sec
    inet6 2806:103e:6:de14:89d9:530c:bc20:bb44/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86070sec preferred_lft 85199sec
    inet6 2806:103e:6:de14:35f7:328a:206f:9d72/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86070sec preferred_lft 86070sec
    inet6 fe80::744b:40fb:f14a:99ea/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see above I have the **loopback interface** and **wlo1 interface**. I will use `wlo1` because that one belongs to wireless connections.

Now, having the network interface(s) you will have to create a script under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.
I will call the script as `10-python-dispatcher.sh` and it will be a shell (**sh**) script. Don't forget to give **execution** permissions to the script, like: `chmod +x 10-python-dispatcher.sh`.

**This will restart myconnection.service if the `wlo1` interface is up or down**

```bash
#/bin/sh

# Scripts under '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/' will have 
# two arguments ($1 and $2) which belong to the device or network interface
# and its status.

DEVICE=${1}
STATE=${2}

if [ "$DEVICE" = "wlo1" ]; then
 
   if [ "$STATE" = "up" -o "$STATE" = "down" ]; then
      systemctl restart myconnection.service
   fi
fi
```

**This will restart myconnection.service only if the `wlo1` interface is up**

```bash
#/bin/sh

DEVICE=${1}
STATE=${2}

if [ "$DEVICE" = "wlo1" ]; then
 
   if [ "$STATE" = "up" ]; then
      systemctl restart myconnection.service
   fi
fi
```

You can adapt the script above to be able to work with any network interface(s) whether this one is up or down.

**Note:** After creating the script under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` I suggest you run the following commands to make sure the dispatcher will run with your current changes:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

You can see [this site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Network_services_with_NetworkManager_dispatcher) by the Arch Wiki to get more info about **NetworkManager**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is working very well. Just one thing, you forgot, that this script should be made executable with `chmod +x`.

Comment: @Matthai oh, sorry, you're right!